# Pasting into a file cleanly using Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to paste an output of a bash script to a text file, but I want to have only the results instead of the whole writings; this is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
result=$(grep -r -i --include=\*.exe ./ > output.txt)
result
```

but what I get in the text file is `Binary file ... matches ..`
Whereas all I want is the names of the files with .exe extension alone each on a different line. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How about a single `find` command `find -type f -exec grep -l "test_my_text" {} \+`? It will provide you only file names which have string `test_my_text` in it only. If you want to look for only specific files then do `find -type f -iname "*.exe" -exec grep -l "test_my_text" {} \+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** In case you only want to print file names while searching specific formats then following may help you.

```
find -type f -iname "*.exe" -printf "%f\n"
```

As per OP, OP wants to take this command in a variable and print the file names into new lines so for that use following.

```
var=$(find -type f -iname "*.exe" -printf "%f\n")
echo "$var"
```

---

Could you please try `find` command which could use `grep` in it for looking for a specific string into file of specific type.

***Solution 1st:*** Simple `find` to look for specific string into the `.exe` files.

```
find -type f -iname "*.exe" -exec grep -l "test_my_text" {} \+
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Use `find` to all kind of files.

```
find -type f -exec grep -l "test_my_text" {} \+
```

Comment: This did indeed show only the file names, but they have no lines between them, all file names are next to each other with no spaces.

Comment: @HiThere, if you are taking them into a variable and printing it use `"` to preserve the lines by doing `echo "$variable"` and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is not the right command for what you want to achieve. What you want is consulting the `find` command for such use cases. Try it like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.exe"
```

Here, `-type f` asks specifically for files (`-type d` would give you directories respectively). You should get your desired output by wrapping it with `$(...)` for further refinement.

Comment: Thank you! this helped, though it still gives me the full path of the files, is there a way to make it spit only the file names?